# if statement in a if statement in a for loop

Tags: linux, bash

It seems that when you use if statement within a if statement that is within a loop, the if statement doesn't iterate through every element.

How should I fix this?

with the following code I am trying to put every `.py` file that fails to execute in `1.log`. But it only puts the first python file found in `1.log`.

```
for i in `find ~/desktop -name '*.py'` ; do 
  if $i ; then 
    true
  else 
    if [[ -e "1.log" ]];then
      echo "$i" > 1.log
    fi
  fi   
done
```

Comment: After this statement : `for i in `find ~/desktop -name '*.py'` ; do ` ,  you get a list of file name so you need loop supplementary to test each files

Comment: You only write `$i` to `1.log` if it already exists, and if it does exist, you completely overwrite its contents with `>` (use `>>` instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `>` redirect which will replace all of the file contents. Use `>>` instead to concatenate.

Also, make sure the file exists before starting the loop (I added a `touch` command for this)

```
touch 1.log
for i in `find ~/desktop -name '*.py'` ; do 
  if $i ; then 
    true
  else 
    if [[ -e "1.log" ]] ; then
      echo "$i" >> 1.log
    fi
  fi   
done
```